# Ordenar lista por semelhança a uma string

Tags: c#, .net, lista, classificação

Tenho uma lista de `string`:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
ABB
ABC
ACC
ACD
```

O usuário irá digitar qual ele está procurando, gostaria de levar para as primeiras posições, as mais parecidas. Exemplo:

String: `A`

Resultado:

```
AAA
ABB
ABC
ACC
ACD
BBB
CCC
```

String: `AB`

Resultado:

```
ABB
ABC
AAA
ACC
ACD
BBB
CCC
```

String: `C`

Resultado:

```
CCC
AAA
ABB
ABC
ACC
ACD
BBB
```

String: `AC`

Resultado:

```
ACC
ACD
AAA
ABB
ABC
CCC
BBB
```

String: `B`

Resultado:

```
BBB
AAA
ABB
ABC
ACC
ACD
CCC
```

Edit:

Apenas incrementando a solução do @maniero que funcionou perfeitamente:

```
lista.OrderByDescending(x => (x.StartsWith(padrao))).ThenByDescending(x => (x.Contains(padrao)));
```

E dessa forma consegui um resultado ainda melhor que o esperado.

Comment: Ordernar ou filtrar?

Comment: Ordenar, não será removido nenhum valor da lista

Comment: Defina semelhança...

Comment: seria a igualdade no inicio da string, o mais próximo de bater com o `StartsWith`

Comment: Com a letra B qual seria a ordem?

Comment: alterei a pergunta com outros exemplos. Obrigado

Comment: Tentei pensar numa alternativa usando quicksort, falhei miseravelmente... As strings não comparam entre si de maneira óbvia, mas com o elemento externo à lista

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O que parece ter sido definido como semelhante é se a *substring* existe na *string* de cada elemento da lista. Então é só ordenar primeiro os que tem, portanto o [`OrderByDecending()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) aplicado no `Contains()`. Ele vai agrupar tudo o que contém e depois o que não contém o padrão de texto.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista = new List<string> { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "ABB", "ABC", "ACC", "ACD" };
        Semelhante(lista, "A");
        Semelhante(lista, "B");
        Semelhante(lista, "C");
        Semelhante(lista, "AB");
        Semelhante(lista, "AC");
    }
    public static void Semelhante(List<string> lista, string padrao) {
        foreach (var item in lista.OrderByDescending(x => (x.Contains(padrao)))) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cuzf9n). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tUU6xy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/OrderStrings.cs).

Em nova edição na pergunta tem uma opção ainda melhor, mas só o AP sabia que era isso que precisava.

---

Anteriormente interpretei de forma diferente o que era semelhança. Fica só para tentar ajudar mais alguém.

Acho que dá para melhorar e não testei totalmente. Alerta de *gambi* pra usar só LINQ :P

O `OrderBy()` espera pelo elemento que deve ser usado para ele classificar ou seja, qual deve ser a chave. Então estou mando para ele a quantidade de ocorrências da *substring* que ele encontrou como chave, afinal quanto mais ocorrências, mais próximo é. usei o `Count()` na *string* para achar o número de ocorrências.

Pode ser que o requisito de "semelhante" não fosse bem esse, mas a pergunta não deixa tão claro. O resultado é o esperado.

Não sei se o AAB é melhor que o ABC porque tem 2 Bs ou se porque o B vem antes de C (o meu pegou assim).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista = new List<string> { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "ABB", "ABC", "ACC", "ACD" };
        var padrao = "A";
        foreach (var item in lista.OrderByDescending(x => x.Select((c, i) => x.Substring(i)).Count(sub => sub.StartsWith(padrao)))) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        padrao = "AB";
        foreach (var item in lista.OrderByDescending(x => x.Select((c, i) => x.Substring(i)).Count(sub => sub.StartsWith(padrao)))) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FFn9uS). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kC2Nki). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/OrderStrings2.cs).

Comment: muito obrigado, estou fazendo alguns testes e ja dou o feedback

Comment: AAB seria melhor que ABC se o `padrao` for `A` pela ordem alfabética mesmo. A quantidade de vezes que o char aparece na string não importa.

Comment: Então como fica `ABC`, `ACA`?

Comment: alterei a pergunta com outros exemplos, Obrigado

Comment: E um `ACA`, onde encaixaria, procurando por `A`. Está parecendo simples demais.

Comment: ACA não teria nenhuma correspondência... ficaria pela ordem alfabética

Comment: Mudei para isto, ainda farei verificações: https://dotnetfiddle.net/B65MB3. Se não for isto está difícil definir o requisito. Talvez precise adicionar uma classificação alfabética (chave composta) para os que são semelhantes ou os que não.

Comment: exatamente isso, muitíssimo obrigado!

Comment: Eu só não chamaria isso de semelhança ;)