# Ordenação customizada em Python

Tags: python, string, classificação, lista

Eu tenho uma lista `foo = ["BCB", "CAB", "CBC"]` e uma ordem alfabética específica `bar = "ACB"`.

O resultado com essa ordem específica deveria ser `resultado = ["CAB", "CBC", "BCB"]`

Como faço para ordenar essa lista?

Comment: Isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/259493/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, pode utilizar o seguinte:

```
foo = ["BCB", "CAB", "CBC"]
bar = "ACB"
foo_new = sorted(foo, 
          key = lambda ordenar: [bar.index(i) if i in bar else ord(i) for i in ordenar])
```

Ou esta,que utiliza sua ordem desejada em dincionario:

```
bar2 = {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'B': 2}
foo2 = ["BCB", "CAB", "CBC"]
foo_new2 = sorted(foo2, 
           key=lambda ordenar: [bar2.get(i, ord(i)) for i in ordenar])
```

Créditos a este tópico do Stackoverflow em inglês : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253274/python-sorting-according-to-a-different-alphabetic-order